# Visualizing .xyz file in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, visualization, chemistry

If i import a .xyz file in Mathematica that will show me the moelcule in the default way. But i want to  visualise the .xyz file in the following manner.
[image]

Comment: Do you have the .xyz file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3rwpedngv5wbqi/ben.xyz?dl=012

Comment: (Editorializing here) Unless you were a [speaker here](http://fe2017.com/), I'm wondering what the motivation for this type of presentation is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticks and balls

```
file = "ben.xyz";

atm = Import[file, "VertexTypes"];
xyz = Import[file];
coord = xyz[[1, 4, 1]];
balls = Cases[xyz[[1, 4, 2]], Sphere[x_, y_] -> {x, y}];
sticks= Cases[xyz[[1, 4, 2]], Cylinder[x_, y_] -> {x, y}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White],
 {Thickness[#[[2]]/1000], Line[coord[[#[[1]]]][[All, 1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ sticks,
 {Disk[coord[[#[[1]]]][[1 ;; 2]], #[[2]]]} & /@ balls,
 Text[Style[atm[[#]], 20, Bold], coord[[#, 1 ;; 2]]] & /@ Range[Length[atm]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a starting point, whose finessing/generalization I will leave to somebody else. First, import the elements and coordinates separately:

```
elem = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/QqrhhvMj", {"XYZ", "VertexTypes"}];
coords = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/QqrhhvMj", {"XYZ", "VertexCoordinates"}];
```

Use an *undocumented* internal function to get bonding information:

```
bonds = UndirectedEdge @@@ Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`InferBonds[elem, coords, 40, 25];
```

From here, you can use `Graph[]` for visualization:

```
Graph[Range[Length[elem]], bonds, 
      EdgeShapeFunction -> ({{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], Black], Line[#1]},
                             {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], Line[#1]}} &),
      GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", 
      VertexLabels -> MapIndexed[First[#2] -> Placed[#1, Center] &, elem], 
      VertexSize -> 0.5, VertexStyle -> GrayLevel[9/10]]
```

[image: benzene]

Here is the corresponding diagram for `Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]`:
[image: caffeine]