# visualizing a normal mode vibration of a molecule in mathematica

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, chemistry

How can I visualize the normal mode vibrations of a molecule in Mathematica? 
Something like the following GIF:

[image: vibrational modes of benzene]
<sup>(from [here](http://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/1318.gif))</sup>

I have the [XYZ file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3rwpedngv5wbqi/ben.xyz?dl=0) of the benzene molecule and the [normal mode coordinates](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pjxams7ndr0l7h/19.mode?dl=0).

Comment: What software makes the `.mode` file?  Is there a standard file format for vibrational modes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using a few undocumented functions that have been discussed here on the stack exchange before,

```
{atoms, coords} = Import[
    "https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3rwpedngv5wbqi/ben.xyz?dl=1",
    {"XYZ", {"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}
];
mode = Most @ Import[
    "https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pjxams7ndr0l7h/19.mode?dl=1", "Table"
];
mode = 100 * mode;
bonds = Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`InferBonds[atoms, coords, 40, 25];
range = Range[-0.5, 0.5, 0.025];
range = Join[range, Reverse @ range];
plot[v_] := ImportExport`MoleculePlot3D[
    {
        "VertexCoordinates" -> (coords + v * mode),
        "VertexTypes" -> atoms, "EdgeRules" -> bonds
    }
];
ListAnimate @ Map[plot, range]
```

[image]

When importing the mode file, it returns an empty list as the last element so I need to use `Most` to make it a matrix.  Then I multiplied it by 100 to convert to picometers. Finally I had to precompute the bonds, because as the molecule moves along the normal coordinate, the atoms could get far enough apart that the bonds wouldn't be detected by `MoleculePlot3D`.

Sources:

1. [Connectivity in a molecule and permutations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130929/9490)
2. [How can I access the internal function that plots a molecule from a formatted XYZ file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24045/9490)
3. [Visualizing .xyz file in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160355/9490)

Comment: Is there any way to make the List Animate window larger so the image is larger in the simulation?

Comment: You should be able to give an `ImageSize` option to the plotting function.